# Compatible High-Power PoE Ethernet Magnetics and PHY

Tags: ethernet, poe

I'm building a high-power (~70-90W) PoE system, anticipating 4-pair power (Type 4 PoE) and am working to select a combination of high-power capable magnetics that is compatible with a basic 10/100 PHY.

The parts I have selected at the moment are:

- Magnetics: [Bel
  S558-5500-JB](https://www.belfuse.com/product/part-details?partn=S558-5500-JB)
- PHY: [Microchip LAN8720A](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/product/LAN8720A)

With some of the Microchip PHYs, they have a selection guide in the datasheet that recommends magnetics with 350uH, however finding high-power PoE-capable magnetics with an inductance of 350uH is extremely difficult/expensive.

My question is, how critical is inductance matching between the PHY and the magnetics?
Can I add inductance to the PHY circuit by inserting ~220uH inductors prior to the PHY?

Comment: The transformer you have chosen is suitable up to 2.5Gbps Ethernet which uses all four pairs. What happens if you only search for 100Mbps compatible transformers for two pairs?

Comment: How well will that work for 4-pair PoE (Type 4)?